# Continuous Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The problem is:

> Verify that the function
>
> ```
>     p: [0,2]  [0,1] given by
>
>     p(X) = {X, if 0 < X < 1
>             2 - X, if 1 < X< 2
> ```
>
> is a  continuous probability density function.

I know in order to be considered a cpdf, f(x) must be positive. It is. And that the integral from -infinity to infinity must equal 1.

In this case that would be the integral of X from 0,1 should equal 1? Same with (2-x) from 1,2?

Comment: It is not necessary for a pdf to be positive, but to be nonnegative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the function $p$ is not the PDF of a real random variable because the PDF of a real random variable is defined on $\mathbb R$ hence one should rather consider the function $q:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by
$$
q(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccl}0&\text{if}&x\leqslant0\\ x&\text{if}&0\lt x\leqslant1\\ 2-x&\text{if}&1\lt x\leqslant2\\ 0&\text{if}& x\gt2\end{array}\right.
$$
Now, $q\geqslant0$ on $\mathbb R$ and
$$
\int_\mathbb Rq(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1x\,\mathrm dx+\int_1^2(2-x)\,\mathrm dx=\text{____},
$$
hence $q$ is indeed a PDF. The continuity is unrelated and it can be checked as for every function.